# Hyperlink only partially clickable

Tags: html, css

So I have just started to learn HTML/CSS and I am trying to create a website for a magazine I'm putting together. However, when I try adding two links to two different pieces of text, one is only partially clickable and the one below is not.

I am thinking it has something to do with my wrapper or the photos I have right beside the text because when I align them more right, they're now clickable. Seems to be like something is blocking part of the word (link) to be clicked on.

I have tried making a sidebar instead but I still get the same result. I tried moving my code around for different results, but still cannot figure it out.

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1140px;
}

.slider {
  max-width: 457px;
  height: 451px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.slide1,
.slide2,
.slide3,
.slide4,
.slide5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide1 {
  background: url(TPWeb.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade 80s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade 20s infinite;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -155px;
}

.slide2 {
  background: url(DS.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade2 80s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade2 20s infinite;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -155px;
}

.slide3 {
  background: url(IT95Web.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade3 80s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade3 20s infinite;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -155px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family:
}

@keyframes fade1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@keyframes fade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}


}
.TPWeb {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.DFBase1 {
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-left: 183px;
  width: 448px;
  height: 127px;
}
.ATA {
  margin-right: 305px;
  margin-top: -475px;
  font-family:
}
.B {
  margin-right: 370px;
  font-family:
}
.about {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.blog {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class='slider'>
    <div class='slide1'></div>
    <div class='slide2'></div>
    <div class='slide3'></div>
  </div>

  <img src="DFBase1.png" alt="DFBase" class=DFBase1>

  <div align="right" class=ATA>
    <font size="5"><em><b><a href="http://google.com" title="about the author" class="about" target="new">about the author</a></b></em></font>
  </div>

  <div align="right" class=B>
    <font size="5"><em><b><a href="http://google.com" title="blog" class="blog" target="new">blog</a></b></em></font>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.slider` is overlapping the links since you're using a negative `margin` to move the links back up on the page.

A simple fix is to give the links a `z-index` by assigning `position: relative`

```css
   .ATA, .B {
position: relative;
   }

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1140px;
}

.slider {
  max-width: 457px;
  height: 451px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.slide1,
.slide2,
.slide3,
.slide4,
.slide5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide1 {
  background: url(TPWeb.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade 80s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade 20s infinite;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -155px;
}

.slide2 {
  background: url(DS.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade2 80s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade2 20s infinite;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -155px;
}

.slide3 {
  background: url(IT95Web.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade3 80s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade3 20s infinite;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -155px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family:
}

@keyframes fade1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@keyframes fade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}


}
.TPWeb {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.DFBase1 {
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-left: 183px;
  width: 448px;
  height: 127px;
}
.ATA {
  margin-right: 305px;
  margin-top: -475px;
  font-family:
}
.B {
  margin-right: 370px;
  font-family:
}
.about {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.blog {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class='slider'>
    <div class='slide1'></div>
    <div class='slide2'></div>
    <div class='slide3'></div>
  </div>

  <img src="DFBase1.png" alt="DFBase" class=DFBase1>

  <div align="right" class=ATA>
    <font size="5"><em><b><a href="http://google.com" title="about the author" class="about" target="new">about the author</a></b></em></font>
  </div>

  <div align="right" class=B>
    <font size="5"><em><b><a href="http://google.com" title="blog" class="blog" target="new">blog</a></b></em></font>
  </div>
</div>
```